# No Ruby icon on '.rb' files after Ruby installation with RailsInstaller on Win XP. How to associate?

Tags: windows-xp, icons, file-association, ruby

At first time I installed Ruby using **RubyInstaller for Windows**. And in the process of installation there was a checkbox whether I want to have `.rb` files to be Ruby files. If I agree all the `.rb` files have Ruby icon:

[image]

But I had to uninstall Ruby and installed it again using **RailsInstaller**. And after that all `.rb` files do not have Ruby icon:

[image]

How can I associate Ruby icon with `.rb` files?

--

If you also need to associate `.rb` files with Ruby interpreter to be able to run Ruby scripts with double-click you can do this (from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Hello_world#Windows)):

```
$ assoc .rb=RubyScript
.rb=RubyScript

$ ftype RubyScript="c:\ruby\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*
RubyScript="c:\ruby\bin\ruby.exe" "%1" %*
```

Comment: You should remove your answer from you question and submit it as answer.

Comment: @martineau, it is not the answer, unfortunately. It only associates `.rb` files with Ruby interpreter - I can double-click a file and it runs. But it does not create the icon on files.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.